# Can I pronounce the first "d" of "didn't" as a flap sound? (American English)

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

As you know in American English if the "d" or "t" is between two vowels in a word or if it is at the end of a word after a vowel and before a word that starts with a vowel, it is pronounced as a flap sound.(Like in "better", "utter" "I cried on his shoulders" etc.) But also in some cases "d" can be pronounced as a flap sound if it is the fist letter of a word too when it's between two vowels. So, I wonder if I can pronounce the first "d" of "didn't" as a flap sound when it comes after a vowel like in "Why didn't she come with us?", "She didn't like me" etc. I know that the second "d" of "didn't" should be pronounced as flap sound but can I also pronounce the first "d" as a flap sound since it's between two vowels and it is not the main verb, or do I have to make the strong "d" sound like in "Days are passing by"? I feel like it sounds smoother and more natural if I make a flap sound at the first "d" of "didn't" too in the sentences like the ones I gave as examples.

I forgot that you can make a flap sound when "d" or "t" is between "r" and a vowel too so can I make that "flap d" sound in the sentences like "My father didn't come", "Harry Potter didn't kill Hagrid" etc. too? It doesn't sound bad to me after a vowel, but after the "r" it sounds weird to me.

Comment: The first syllable of *didn't* is probably stressed in *Why didn't she come with us?* so you shouldn't use a flap for the first /d/.

Comment: @Peter Shor Thanks. So shouldn't I pronounce the first "d" of "didn't" as a flap sound in any case? Or don't Americans ever pronounce that first "d" of "didn't" as a flap sound after a vowel?

Comment: We never flap /d/ or /t/ before a stressed syllable. You can pronounce the first /d/ as a flap if the word *didn't* isn't stressed. We usually stress *didn't*, but if you're saying something like "***I*** didn't do it," where you put stress on *I* instead, you can flap the /d/ in *didn't*. And very often, we flap the first syllable of *did*, which usually isn't stressed.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks again. But if the word that starts with a "d" is a content word, we can't make a flap sound at that first "d" right? For example in the sentence "I am going to do it another day" Since both _do_ and _day_ are content words, I shouldn't make a flap sound at these words despite the fact that they are unstressed, right?

Comment: Also in American accent if a person doesn't pronounce the "d" at the beginning of a word as a flap sound despite the fact that it can be pronounced that way, does it sound unnatural? Do Americans always make that flap sound when the "d" at the beginning of a word can be pronounced as flap sound like in "Why did he come with you?"

Comment: @PeterShor I am sorry. I accidentally wrote that way. I changed it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69346/discussion-between-derememo-and-peter-shor).

Comment: If you pronounce the /d/ at the beginning of a word as a /d/ when it could be a flap, it will sound fine. But I've heard somebody pronounce ***all*** their /d/s and /t/s, and not use flaps for any of them. It sounded like he had a foreign accent, but his speech was perfectly understandable. (Not a British accent, because he pronounced his vowels the American way. I couldn't identify his accent as any specific country, but I'm not that good at pinpointing foreign accents.)

Comment: @PeterShor So, Americans from time to time(maybe some Americans do it often) pronounce the "d" at the beginning of a word as a true "d" sound even if it can be pronounced as a flap. But if I "always" make a true "d" sound instead of the flap, it will sound unnatural. I got it right, didn't I?  Also can I please get your answer about the question I asked before the last one?

Comment: A note about my question on not making flap at content words: Actually for example saying _I will see him two days later._ by making a flap at "day" sounds more natural to me despite the fact that "day" is a content word as far as I know. I am confused.

Comment: I got one more question: Should I make a flap when I say "Yes I did" too as an answer to a question like "Did you see them"? I think since "do" is not the main verb here, I can make a flap here at "did" but if I say "I did" as an answer to a question like "Did you do it", I should make a "true d" sound since "do" is the main verb here. But for "do", I should make a true  d sound anyway when I say "Yes I do", right?

Comment: you have the general idea. I think the rules are really very loose, so native speakers might flap the /d/ in *I will see him two days later*.

Comment: Hm...as an American I don't think I ever flap any /d/ at the start of a word. In fact, I don't even flap the second /d/ in didn't. I just omit it....I say [dInt] or [dIn] (unless I'm in a super formal setting where I need to sound proper.)

Comment: @mlecoz But you mostly flap the /d/'s at the ends of words if the next word is starting with a vowel and if there is a vowel or an /r/ sound before the /d/ right? I mean in the sentences like "I trie**d** again", "I crie**d** on her shoulders" "This ki**d** is nice", "He is not ba**d** after all" etc. you flap the d's, right?

Comment: @PeterShor I think we can flap the initial /d/'s in these sentences as well, am I right? *"Where does he work?", "Where did she go?", "Where do you live?" and "Where don't you want to go?"*

Comment: I wouldn't. Unless I was speaking carefully enough not to flap /d/s, I'd say *Where'd she go?"* and *Where daya live?* And *don't* gets enough stress to stop the /d/ from flapping.

Comment: Thank you. Do they sound weird to you when you make an initial flap sound when you pronounce those sentences? For example, does /weɹ ɾu ju/ sound weird to you?

Comment: Saying *Where don't you want to go?* without stressing *don't* sounds weird; *Where do you live?* sounds fine with the flap. For the other two, I'd expect a contraction.

Answer (score 2):

No, the first "d" of "didn't" is a regular "d" sound, apico-alveolar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good at hearing the difference between a voiced alveolar flaps/taps and a voiced alveolar stop, but I think I can use a tap/flap in sentences like "I didn't go to the store today". (I would expect this to be true because I feel like the /d/ at the start of "didn't" can almost be elided entirely in this position.) I feel the same way about "didn't" in "She didn't like me".

I'm less sure about the "didn't" in "Why didn't she come with us?", because I feel like depending on how I say the sentence, there might be more stress on it than in the other sentences (as Peter Shor said in a comment).